# update_sub_field() with repeater not working

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having troubles creating a field using Advanced Custom Field's update_field() and / or update_sub_field() that is a repeater row inside of a group.

**Structure is as such:**

> group >
>   repeater >
>   field

See attached screenshots [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoREW.png)

I have tried the following approaches, outside of the loop:

```
update_field( 'system_preset_1_inverter_group', 'test_data' , $new_quote_id );

update_sub_field( array('system_preset_1_inverter_group', 1, 'inverter'), 'test_data' , $new_quote_id );

update_sub_field( array('system_preset_1', 1, 'inverter_group', 1, 'inverter'), 'test_data' , $new_quote_id );
```

None of which actually add a row to the repeater with any data.

Note, this is a custom post type that is being created programatically, and as such, the admin is never touched, and the fields never created via the admin page. Also note, update_field() is working with other groups and individual fields.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I have also tried this, to no avail:
`update_sub_field( array('system_preset_1', 1, 'system_preset_1_inverter_group', 1, 'inverter'), 'test_data' , $new_quote_id ); `

Comment: This is probably not the right way of doing it, but I've found a workaround for anyone interested.

`update_field( 'system_preset_1_inverter_group' , count($system_preset_1_inverters), $new_quote_id );

      $preset_1_flag = 0;
      foreach ( $system_preset_1_inverters as $insert_inverter_1 ) {
        update_field( 'system_preset_1_inverter_group_' . $preset_1_flag . '_inverter' , $system_preset_1_inverter_brand . ' ' . $insert_inverter_1, $new_quote_id );
        $preset_1_flag++;
      }`

Comment: On second thought... this doesn't create top level groups. May have to resort to using field keys for every single field...?